# Query elasticsearch match return inexact document

Tags: json, elasticsearch, lucene

I'm trying to retrieve random documents that contain `#maga` so I did the following query:

```
{
  "_source": "text", 
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "text": "#maga"
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "random_score": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is some returned document doesn't contain `#maga` but just the token `maga`. Why so? And How can I ivercome this problem?

Comment: Your `text` field is probably an analyzed string field and the `#` sign has been removed at indexing time. You can try to use a `term` query instead of  a `match` and see if this solves the issue.

Comment: It return nothing when I query using term (o documents)

Comment: Ok, then it's because your `text` field is analyzed and the `#` sign is removed during analysis. You need to make that field a `keyword` instead of `text`.

Comment: @mel Can you provide mapping of `text` field? If possible please provide some sample document you are trying to match against? Probably you need to use different `analyzer` like `whitespace` ..